# Very basic authentication - is that sufficient?

Tags: php, web

I wrote my app in PHP, and I want to have access to some variabes on running site. I just add an extra page, with some var_dumps. I validate it with this method:

```
if((isset($_POST['pass']))&&($_POST['pass']=="mypassword")){
var_dump();
 .
 .
 .
 .
}else{
echo'NO';
}
```

Is that sufficient for a small intranet website?

Comment: Only you can know what kind of users you have, and what value the information you're showing might tell them. It's terrible security, but it might be enough for what you need in this specific instance.

Comment: Look into hashing the password, and get into the habit of never storing clear passwords server-side or, even worse, directly in your code. Also, refrain from using `==`, `===` is almostt always what you really want; You don't want the values you're comparing to be arbitrarily cast before you compare them.

Comment: Although it is not a recommended way, I do it sometimes too :) In fact, I do it for pages that no one else is supposed to know that they even exist. Those kind of pages are not worth spending time to be created perfectly.

Comment: What's your web-server? It's usually a few minutes work to set up HTTP Auth authentication, which is already a step forward. Still not perfect, but at least better

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your application. For example you may secure your house with a $20 lock but for a bank they spend much much more. If you don't have valuable information that is worth spending a lot of time and energy for others to crack your security, that is fine.